# Why is variable showing as undefined on line 67?

Tags: python, undefined

I am new to python and in this simple code keep getting the undefined error for price1 on line 67 where I am trying to get the order total. But, as far as I can see it is defined for each item. Any help is appreciated.

CODE SCRIPT:

```
print("Hello! \n" + "Welcome to Longview Coffee!")

name = input("What is your name? \n")

#greeting with custom name, present menu
print("\n Hello " + name + " thank you for coming in today! \n")
print("Here is what we are serving today? \n")
print("Coffee \n" + "Latte\n" + "Frap\n" + "Brownie\n" + "Cookie \n\n")

#end user inputs their selection
print("Please make your selection")
order1 = input()
if order1 == "frap":
 price1 = 8
elif order1 == "lattee":
 price1 = 6
elif order1 == "coffee":
 price1 = 4
elif order1 == "brownie":
 price1 = 2
elif order1 == "cookie":
 price1 = 2

#end user is requested to tell how many of the item they want
quantity1 = input("How many " + order1 + "s would you like?\n")

#end user is asked if there is anything else to add to order
print("Is there anything else you would like to order today? \n")
answer2 = input()
if answer2 == "yes":
  print("Please make your next selection. \n")
  order2 = input()
  if order2 == "frap":
    price2 = 8
  elif order2 == "lattee":
    price2 = 6
  elif order2 == "coffee":
    price2 = 4
  elif order2 == "brownie":
    price2 = 2
  elif order2 == "cookie":
    price2 = 2
  quantity2 = input("How many " + order2 + "s would you like?\n")
  print("Alright, " + name + " your order will be ready very soon. \n")
  
elif answer2 == "no":
  total = price1 * int(quantity1)
  print("\nOkidoki, your total for todays order of comes to $" + str(total) + "\n")
total = price1 * int(quantity1) + price2 * int(quantity2)
print("\nOkidoki, your total for todays order of comes to $" + str(total) +
      "\n")
```

Checked each line to make sure I didn't leave a item undefined. Made sure indentations were in line with statements (as far as I could tell).

Comment: `price1` variable is ONLY set inside of an `if` block. In the case that `order1` variable isn't equal to `frap`, `lattee`, `coffee`, `brownie`, or `cookie` then `price1` will be undefined. Consider, after `order1 = input()` to initiate that variable with a line that reads `price1 = 0`. Or, conversely, in your if block, add an `else: price1=0` so that it is definitely set. You'll run into the same problem with `price2` so consider initiating that with a value of `0` at the top of your code as well.

Comment: `price1` isn't defined if all the `if` statements fail.

Comment: You really need a final `else:` on both of those `if`/`elif` chains, to catch the case of the user entering an unknown value.

Comment: You may want to use an `else` statement in case orders are different than the options listed